Debian/Ubuntu: Change touchpad sensitivity
I want to change my touchpad sensitivity on Debian (or its derivative like Ubuntu, etc.). How can do it?

Like so (on Debian bullseye):

The parameters you're interested in are speed and acceleration. Query
j@db7280:~$ synclient -l | grep 'ccel\|eed'
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0582581
    CoastingSpeed           = 20

The important parameters are MaxSpeed and AccelFactor
(the higher, the faster the pointer will move).

Check if there's a (synaptics) config file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d. If there is, edit it as specified below. If there isn't, do (your file name may differ):
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics-j.conf

and edit the one in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d (those in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d may get overwritten). 
Specifically, the section
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
#      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
       Option "MaxSpeed" "1.75"
       Option "AccelFactor" "0.0582581"
EndSection

changing MaxSpeed and AccelFactor to your liking.

Query apt-cache policy libevdev2. 
If you have it installed, uncomment the MatchDevicePath line.

Save the config file and log out. 
After logging in again, the sensitivity should be changed.



Those are some really old instructions. It's good that xf86-input-synaptics still works for you, but in general it was superseded by -libinput all the way back in Debian buster (assuming the system is still using Xorg to begin with)...so at some point I expect you'll have to switch over.

@u1686_grawity You may be right there. I noticed I have xinput instructions too, but synaptics makes more sense to me (also, I don't have xinput installed)
